# Programatically creating a view controller view using an external class

Tags: view, controller

I'm trying to create a class that will allow me to easily implement tutorial screen "overlays" within any view controller.  I'm using the following as a reference:

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/824_Creating_Pulse_Application_Like_Tutorial_Overlay.aspx

So, my hope would be I could create a class ( i.e. TutorialOverlay.h / TutorialOverlay.m ), and then inside a  given view controller (i.e. VievController.h / ViewController.m ) I could instantiate an instance of that class and create a tutorial screen overlay by doing something like this:

@property (nonatomic,strong) TutorialOverlay *tutorialScreen;
@synthesize tutorialScreen = _tutorialScreen;

self.tutorialScreen = [[TutorialOverlay alloc] initWithValues:@"specialscreen.png"];
[self.tutorialScreen showScreen];

Where I'm stuck is this:  Since I squirreled all the code from the highoncoding.com example into this external class ( i.e. TutorialOverlay.h / TutorialOverlay.m ), that code can't do the last [self.view addSubview:topView] because the external class can't see/use the view in the view controller that called it.

I'm not sure whaere to go to make this work - delegates?  Make TutorialOverlay.h / TutorialOverlay.m a subclass of UIView?

Any help and guidance appreciated - it would be nice to be able to whip these type of tutorial screens out at easily and add extra logic that would make them only run the first time an app runs, etc. rather than re-code the methods in every view controller!